# Unzip with Paramiko - Python

Tags: python, zip, sudo, paramiko

I have a script to upload a zip file through sftp with the Paramiko module. I'm trying to unzip the zip file, but it's not working. I don't get any feedback that says it's not working.

```
import paramiko, re

spaceNeeded = 11534336
localpath = 'C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\10_Recommended.zip'
remotepath = '/tmp/10_Recommended.zip'
sudopass = "password"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host', username='username', password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr =ssh.exec_command("df -k /tmp | grep /tmp | tr -s ' ' ',' | cut -d ',' -f4")
actualSpace = ''.join(stdout.readlines())

if actualSpace > spaceNeeded:
    transport = paramiko.Transport(('host',22))
    transport.connect(username="username", password="password")
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
    print "Starting upload"
    sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
    stdin, stdout, stderr =ssh.exec_command("ls /tmp | grep 10_Recommended.zip")
    zipfile = ''.join(stdout.readlines())
    print "Unzipping file"

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("unzip /tmp/10_Recommended.zip")
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?  What makes you think it *should* work?

Comment: I know it's not working because I ssh to the machine and look....

Comment: If you execute the commands when you are logged in through ssh, do they work?

Comment: Yes, the unzip commands work then. All the other commands work as well in my script, just not the unzip. It doesn't require a sudo either.

Comment: What if you provide the full path to the unzip command?

Comment: I tried that as well with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Your ssh connection may be closed before unzipping is done. I had a similar problem and added `stdout.read()` after `exec_command` to force the connection to be open until unzip is done.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 3 months old, but I think I just fixed a similar issue and decided to contribute.

Try making the following change:

```
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
print "Starting upload"
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close() #this should block until put finishes
stdin, stdout, stderr =ssh.exec_command("ls /tmp | grep 10_Recommended.zip")
```

Comment: `put` method is synchronous. `close` cannot help. If it helped, then only by a chance (e.g. by slightly delaying the `exec_command`, so that some unrelated background process finishes, like an antivirus scan of the newly uploaded file).

Answer (score -2):

Using `tar` replace `unzip` works for me.

I thought `unzip` is not pure Linux command.